# How do you develop with Intellij on Windows and Java and deploy to Azure Service Fabric

Tags: java, windows, azure, intellij-idea, azure-service-fabric

I'm using Intellij and Java, on a Windows development machine and Windows launch host target.  The use of service Fabric has come into discussion but when I look at docs it presumes you're either using Visual Studio (and probably C#) and building/deploying to Service Fabric as SF project, or that your linux developer using eclipse and want to package to deploy to Service Fabric.

Intellij Azure tools doesn't look like it supports Service Fabric. The Eclipse Service Fabric plugin says it doesn't work in Windows (Linux only)

So how can a Windows/Java developer build and deploy to Service Fabric if you don't want to move to Visual Studio, change language, but you want to dev in Windows with Java?

Has any one found a simple way that this can be achieved?

I'd prefer NOT to have to jump off Intellij, definitely want to use Java (and Spring Boot), and interested in how I package and deploy to Service Fabric on Windows dev laptop (local 1 node cluster, Azure multinode cluster later).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's documentation for Azure Service Fabric has [a section on manually packaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app#manually-package-and-deploy-an-existing-executable) an existing EXE (editing the XML configuration files) along with the Powershell scripts to [push the package out to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app#deployment).

I would think in most cases, the initial set up of the XML files and Powershell scripts would be a one-time thing and then you just re-use them for each deployment.

Comment: so sounds like i'm out on a limb then using java on windows from azure perspective with liitle tooling support.  Seems odd.  C'est la vie - I guess i'll just try and have a moan at MS and see what happens